# redshift cluster update killing query speed

Tags: amazon-redshift

So every night I have a sql build script that runs in Redshift that takes about 30 min. This has been consistent for over a year.

After an amazon cluster update last night the script now takes 6 hours!

Has anyone had this problem before?

Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the change list in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3619 the only thing I see that might impact you is that now you have to specify a sort threshold on vacuums, so your tables might not be getting resorted and it could drastically impact performance.  Other than that, I'd run some explain plans on your queries and see what's taking the biggest amount of resources.  It could be that growing tables have hit some threshold of slice skew.

Comment: thanks, I guess it was a problem on their end. You just have to wait it out.
this is what they said 
"After a node replacement is performed, the data backups(block replicas) need to be replicated from the other nodes back to the replaced node. While replication is occurring the cluster performance will be degraded. "